# SqlConnection.Open fails randomly

Tags: sql-server, sqlconnection

I have been facing a strange issue. I have a code snippet like below:

```
SqlTransaction transaction = null;
SqlDataReader reader = null;

using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_sqlEndpoint.ConnectionString))
{
     sqlConnection.Open(); **// Randomly fails here**

    try
    {
        switch (_sqlEndpoint.ResultType)
        {
        case ResultSetType.None:
            transaction = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(_sqlEndpoint.Query, sqlConnection, transaction))
            {
                command.CommandTimeout = _sqlEndpoint.CommandTimeout;
                int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                exchange.Message.SetHeader("RowsAffected", rowsAffected);
            }
            break;

        case ResultSetType.Single:
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(_sqlEndpoint.Query, sqlConnection))
            {
                command.CommandTimeout = _sqlEndpoint.CommandTimeout;
                exchange.Message.Body = command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            break;

        default:
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(_sqlEndpoint.Query, sqlConnection))
            {
                command.CommandTimeout = _sqlEndpoint.CommandTimeout;
                reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                exchange.Message.Body = reader;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
         Log.ErrorFormat("[{0}] Error occured while fetching data from sql server: {1}", _sqlEndpoint.RouteName, ex.Message);
    }                
}
```

The connection opens 9 out of 10 times and then fails with the following exception:
**"The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction"**

Again is able to connect the 11th time and then fails randomly the 19th time or so. This doesnt happen in the dev environment, only in production.

I have tried/checked the following:

- Changing the connection string to use UserId and Password creds instead of SSPI to eliminate any AD related issues
- Tried Clearing the specific connection from the pool by calling SqlConnection.ClearPool(conn) so that a new connection is made rather than getting from the pool
- Checked that MSDTC service is running on the production server

I am running out of ideas on this one. I am not even sure how to reproduce this error on the dev machine.

Any help or pointers will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: yes, this code runs as a part of cron jobs and is executed multiple times (so multiple connections)

Comment: Are you using shared server for your production environment?

Comment: The DB server is dedicated, however, the application server is running multiple other apps.